# apache + passenger just listing files in public dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos, passenger

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ... server name/aliases and such.

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  RackEnv staging
  RackBaseURI /extapp/forms

  <Directory /var/www/html/extapp/forms>
    Options -MultiViews 
    PassengerRuby /home/pstn/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

`/var/www/html/extapp/forms` is  a symlink linking to the `public` folder of a rails 4 application, all permissions for the directory tree are correct (r+w).

Passenger boots, as per the entry in the logs:

```
[ 2014-09-08 14:07:17.5896 21559/7f8d77305720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
```

However, when I visit the appropriate path, all I get is a directory listing of the files residing in the `public` folder (i.e. robots.txt et. al.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Directory /var/www/html/extapp/forms>
Options -MultiViews 
PassengerRuby /home/posten/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

Then restart the server.

My server config is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerName mysite
    RailsEnv development
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
            PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ruby-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ruby-access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that didn't do anything.

Comment: Why you are using symlinks?

Comment: That's the way our setup is at the company.